# FullCalendar: Unable to dynamically update the Events array

Tags: fullcalendar

I am working on a Time Off calendar (only using the *month* display mode).

I want to prevent multiple events on the same day. Here's what my code looks like (it's simplified for the purpose of this question).

```
// Get current Events.
var currentEvents = $('#calendar').fullCalendar('option', 'events');

// Do validation process here...

var newTimeOffEvent = {
    title:      'Time Off',
    start:      $('#txtStartDate').val(),
    end:        $('#txtEndDate').val(),
    allDay:     true,
    editable:   true
};

// Render the new single event on the calendar.
$('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', newTimeOffEvent, true);

// Trying to update the Events array in the Full Calendar.
$('#calendar').fullCalendar('option', 'events', $.merge([], currentEvents, [newTimeOffEvent]));
```

The last line of code doesn't seem to works since on the following executions of the code, the new event isn't in the array of Events.

I've tried many functions found in the [Full Calendar's doc](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/) to update the Events array but without success:
*updateEvents(method)*, *clientEvents(method)*, etc...

Maybe there's a combination of functions I didn't think about...

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It works! I just didn't used the right function to retrieve the current Events in the Full Calendar. Instead of *option > events*, I needed to call the function *clientEvents*, see below:

```
// Get current Events.
var currentEvents = $('#calendar').fullCalendar('clientEvents');

// Do validation process here...

var newTimeOffEvent = {
    title:      'Time Off',
    start:      $('#txtStartDate').val(),
    end:        $('#txtEndDate').val(),
    allDay:     true,
    editable:   true
};

// Render the new single event on the calendar.
$('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', newTimeOffEvent, true);
```

The block of code below isn't useful anymore since the *renderEvent* is updating *clientEvents*:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar('option', 'events', $.merge([], currentEvents, [newTimeOffEvent]));
```

In hope that my confusion has helped someone.